Quick Connects used in pressure washers
I am looking for a specification, patent or any other document or source which describes those quick connectors used in pressure washers often sold on AliExpress or Amazon. They come commonly in 1/4" size, and have various types of threads depending on the manufacturer.
photos of quick connectors in question

just Google air hose fittings

Start with the detailed data sheets for the products.
